# How to custom format excel cell containing 0 or BLANK value to -?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to format cells on a column of an excel(with general or number values). So if a cell had a 0 and I would like to replace with a "-". Hence I use the custom format
*

> *(* #,##0*);*(* (#,##0);*(* "-"??*);*(@_)

*

**But if a cell has 0 or BLANK value, how do I modify the above format to also show "-" for BLANK values?**

Comment: There is no cell format part applied to empty value.

Comment: You cannot. You could use a VBA event-triggered macro, though.

Comment: @Akina Ok. Then how can I show 0 in a number column/cell, whenever it is Blank or Zero?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Same query as to Akina.

Comment: You would use VBA to fill the blank cell however you want. Depending on your application, you may have to also intercept all calculation calls, to actually remove the cell contents (and then replace your token), if your application/formula needs that cell to really be blank.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I am trying to avoid VBA, cause the sheet is going to be shared with other users who might not be able to enable macros while using the sheet. Hence it defeats the purpose. Nevertheless thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: Then you are going to have to change the **contents** of the cell. You will have to either replace the blank cell with a `0` (and format it to show a `-`, or replace the blank cell with a `-`.  You can do that with a `Find/Replace`, or by filling the blank cells with a formula.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Exactly. I am seeking help with regard to filling the blank cell with 0 using a formula(not VBA). If that happens, then my original formula i.e (* #,##0);(* (#,##0);(* "-"??);(@_) will start working.

Comment: A formula can only alter the cell in which it is located.  So, without VBA, you will either need to have the contents of every cell dependent on the formula within that cell, or do a `Find/Replace` over the area to replace all blank cells with zero's. (Method 1 or Method 2 of Rajesh)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- For 1st part of your problem, the Cell format you are trying can be used, also this may be used.

  `0;-0;—;@`
- As per my knowledge to replace `BLANK` with `Dash`, Excel doesn't provides any *Custom Cell Format*, but yes there are few other methods.

---

**Method 1.**

- Select cells, press **CTRL+G**.
- Select **Blanks option**.
- Type `-`.
- Finally press **Ctrl+Enter**.

---

**Method 2:**

Select required cell range.

- Press **Ctrl+H**
- For **Find what** leave the field empty.
- For **Replace with** type `-`.
- Finally press **Replace all.**

---

**Method 3:**

*You may use this VBA macro as **M**odule.*

```
Sub ReplaceBlanks()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range

On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "Replace Blanks & Zeros"

Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)

For Each Rng In WorkRng
     If Rng.Value = "" Or Rng.Value = 0 Then
        Rng.Value = "-"
    End If
    Rng.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Next
End Sub
```

**N.B.**

*This fills all cells contains blank & Zeros  in the selected range with Dash sign.*

- Either press **A**lt+F11 or **R**ight click the Sheet TAB  and hit **V**iew Code, to open  VB editor.
- From **I**nsert menu hit **M**odule.
- **C**opy & **P**aste this code.
- *Save the Workbook as **M**acro Enabled.*
- Finally **R**UN the macro.

---

**Method 4:**

- *Suppose you are getting ZERO after applied a formula.*

`=IF(SUM(A1:E1)=0,"-",SUM(A1:E1))`

Comment: Although your solution may be acceptable, you should point out that your solution changes not only the **appearance** (as would be done by formatting) but also the **value** of the cell.  If the OP is using formulas that rely on the cell actually being empty, your solution may cause unexpected results.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld,, thanks for the observation,, I guess  that U are trying to point out Method 4,, since OP is struggling with Zero to replace with dash therefore the suggested formula only focus on that,,, since OP has not suggested any sample data therefore difficult to think about another possibilities.

Comment: @RajeshS actually my main concern is with Blanks in a cell. For zero my the custom format mentioned works fine. Even in cases of cells which has a 0 value, if I delete it, it goes back to going Blank instead of a "-" hence the issue. So an applicable solution would have been to replace the 0 and Blank both with "-". But as pointed out by the other users, its not possible.

Comment: @anand,, I think that still you have not tried any of the suggested method better try what I've been suggested instead of other's view point,, what I've suggested ,, have been tested for the job, before I've posted them as answer. **You may use Find & Replace or the Formula I've suggested,, also the VBA macro. Better you use the Macro, let me modify  the post,, it will works for both `BLANKs` & `Zeros` !!**

Comment: @anand,, now I've modified the MACRO (Method 3),, read carefully the instruction and RUN it, will works for both Blank as well for Zeros!!

Comment: @RajeshS Thank you for the suggestions

Comment: Glad to help you @anand ,, keep asking ☺